# Is it beneficial to development to use a case-sensitive file system?

Tags: macos, filesystems, case-sensitive

Is there any benefit to developing on a case sensitive file system?

I recently heard that Adobe products do not run on case sensitive file systems. Is developing on a case-sensitive file system the simplest way to avoid such problems?

Comment: I can't even think of any non-case sensitive file systems.

Comment: @Ink-Jet: ever worked on a mainframe? ever thought about Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question:  No, you'll run into equivalent problems when your product is deployed to case *insensitive* file systems like the default configuration of HFS+ which is the file system on any Mac OS X box.

The best strategy is to build it on whatever your dev machine is and test it on both case sensitive and insensitive systems.  If you have a default Mac OS X installation, your file system is case insensitive.  One way to get a case sensitive file system is to use disk utility to create a case sensitive read/write disk image.

Of course, you'll still not be testing against a completely case sensitive environment - ~/Library/Application Support would still be on a case insensitive system.  You'd probably need to create a user whose home directory is a symlink to your case sensitive disk image.  I don't know if that would work, I've never tried it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd always recommend to avoid requirements. Having a case-insensitive file system is such a requirement. Having a case-sensitive file system is another one (to allow files with same name but different casing).

Additionally, I'd always recommend to develop on a system that is as close to production as possible.

Comment: Avoid requirements?  I'm going to use that one in our sprint planning meeting on Monday, lol

Comment: +1 for "... I'd always recommend to develop on a system that is as close to production as possible."

Comment: @echo if you manage to avoid every last one of them you could make yourself a vacation sprint ;)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than developing on a system just because it has case sensitivity, which is quite a big constrain, you can more pragmatically:

- design so that it can behave correctly on case-sensitive FS
- run tests on it, after thinking of what tests will spot case-sensitivity problems

Comment: and neither rely on behaviour that applies to case-sensitive or case insensive filesystems... eg 2 Files with same name but different case, or read delivered files with hardcoded filenames whose case does not match the actual file...